# Get HTML by evaluating JavaScript in a WKWebView

Tags: javascript, html, ios, swift, wkwebview

I'm working with a `WKWebView` in my iOS app and after loading a webpage and I want to get the HTML of gmail.com. I have this expression in a function that I call in ViewDidAppear:

```
func getHTML() {
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.documentElement.outerHTML.toString()", completionHandler: { (html: Any?, error: Error?) in
           print(html)
    })
}
```

However, when I run this function, I get the following output in the console:

```
Optional(<html><head></head><body></body></html>)
```

What am I doing wrong? Gmail isn't the only webpage that gives me this result – every page I tried gives me the same output.

Here is all of my code:

```
// MARK: Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = URL(string: "https://www.gmail.com")!
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)

    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    self.webView.load(request)
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    getHTML() // the function posted above
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the webpage wasn't fully loaded! I was calling my function in ViewDidAppear but after I added a button and called the javascript when I pressed the button, I got the HTML I was looking for.